# Allocate array of structure dynamically in C - Is this code desirable?

Tags: c, pointers, structure

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct _Node {
    int* connectedNodeList;
}Node;
int numOfNode = 5;
int main() {
    Node* nodeList = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node) * numOfNode);
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfNode; i++) {
        nodeList[i].connectedNodeList = calloc(numOfNode, sizeof(int));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfNode; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numOfNode; j++) {
            printf("%d ", nodeList[i].connectedNodeList[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Is this code desirable?
Results are fine, but compiler says some warning about buffer overrun.
I wonder if this code is safe.

The error is:

```
Warning C6386   Buffer overrun while writing to 'nodeList':
  the writable size is 'sizeof(Node)*numOfNode' bytes,
  but '8' bytes might be written.
```

Comment: Not seeing the problem. Do you still get the warning if you remove the cast, or replace malloc with calloc?

Comment: Compiled and ran on my machine without errors or warnings. (As a side note, you should return something from `main` and `free` all the dynamically allocated memory.)

Comment: Can you identify the exact line referred to by the warning?

Comment: As others have mentioned, the shown code seems unlikely to cause the quoted warning. Please insert a `#error This code is actually compiled. Good.` into your code file, compile again and report what happens.

Comment: Could replacing the malloc with a calloc remove the warning ? To me, it looks like an error in the compiler. There is no error in the code.

Comment: nodeList[i]->connectedNodeList instead of nodeList[i]. connectedNodeList

Comment: @VioAriton `nodeList[i]->connectedNodeList` literally makes no sense, and wouldn't even compile with the posted code. Given the type of `nodeList`, it isn't valid C.